# UIActivityViewController and facebook/twitter

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I know how to using the `SocialFramework` add images/urls to the facebook/twitter sharing functionality. All I am looking for is how to do it using the UIActivityViewController share sheet.

I know there is a second optional attribute you can pass on the array. Is it possible to do it there?

```
 let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareContent as NSString], applicationActivities: nil)
        presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

activityItems is a `[AnyObject]`. For example: `let activityItems = [ UIImage(), "A string", NSURL() ]`.

There is a list here of which services support what type of objects.
http://nshipster.com/uiactivityviewcontroller/